# SKLearn PCA explained_variance_ration cumsum gives array of 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-analysis, pca, variance

I have a problem with PCA. I read that PCA needs clean numeric values. I started my analysis with a dataset called `trainDf` with shape `(1460, 79)`.

I did my data cleaning and processing by removing empty values, imputing and dropping columns and I got a dataframe `transformedData` with shape `(1458, 69)`.

Data cleaning steps are:

1. `LotFrontage` imputing with mean value
2. `MasVnrArea` imputing with 0s (less than 10 cols)
3. Ordinal encoding for categorical columns
4. `Electrical` imputing with most frequent value

I found outliers with IQR and got `withoutOutliers` with shape `(1223, 69)`.

After this, I looked at histograms and decided to apply `PowerTransformer` on some features and `StandardScaler` on others and I got `normalizedData`.

Now I tried doing PCA and I got this:

```py
pca = PCA().fit(transformedData)

print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())

plt.plot(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')
```

the output of this PCA is the following:

```
[0.67454179 0.8541084  0.98180307 0.99979932 0.99986346 0.9999237
 0.99997091 0.99997985 0.99998547 0.99999044 0.99999463 0.99999719
 0.99999791 0.99999854 0.99999909 0.99999961 0.99999977 0.99999988
 0.99999994 0.99999998 0.99999999 1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.        ]
```

[image: PCA1]

Then I tried:

```py
pca = PCA().fit(withoutOutliers)

print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())

plt.plot(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')
```

out:

```
[0.68447278 0.86982875 0.99806386 0.99983727 0.99989606 0.99994353
 0.99997769 0.99998454 0.99998928 0.99999299 0.9999958  0.99999775
 0.99999842 0.99999894 0.99999932 0.99999963 0.9999998  0.9999999
 0.99999994 0.99999998 0.99999999 1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.        ]
```

[image: PCA2]

Finally:

```py
pca = PCA().fit(normalizedData)

print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())

plt.plot(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')
```

Out:

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

[image: PCA3]

How is it possible that the last execution gives such an output?

Here are data distributions

`transformedData`

[image: transformedData hist]

`withoutOutliers`

[image: withoutOutliers hist]

`normalizedData`

[image: normalizedData hist]

I'll add any further data if necessary, thanks in advance to any who can help!

Comment: Coul you share the data? Looks like that you transformations just create a rank 1 matrix

Comment: I'm a beginner, just using the Kaggle dataset for house prices https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques what should I share? Do you need the complete transformations I perform on the data? I'm currently building different pipeline steps, I'll add the steps

Comment: @SimonHawe I added further details, are this enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, all data should be scaled before applying PCA (for example using a [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)).

I got the answer on [Data science stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/107808/sklearn-pca-explained-variance-ration-cumsum-gives-array-of-1/107952#107952).